# Combining CSS files into a single cached one

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm creating a theme where i want it to have different widgets and plugins. Each plugin would ideally have it's own css file. However, this approach is not so good because i can end up having multiple files included in my header.

Is there an approach where i can sort of cache all different css files in a single one upon the first user request and then just use that ?

Comment: Is this WordPress or something?

Comment: Yes, there are many tools that will do this for you. If you need an automated process, it will depend on what the theme is for, and the server technology it runs on. Let us know more details so we can narrow down the list for you!

Comment: minitech, yes it's for wordpress :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use only one css with all the different styles from each plugin in that single file. This way you'll end up having only one external css file and it will be cached, saving bandwitdh and decreasing loading times of the page.

Comment: i know about that already, but it's not what i want :) And i don't like a single css for every possible custom plugin that i create.

Comment: If you just want to remove the css references from the header while still mantaining separate css files, maybe you should use the @import feature in the single css file you want to keep, so you have one single link tag in the header but each css file remains separate from the others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at things like yui compressor http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still interested, I created a PHP class that combines all the files .css or .js files of the specified folder into one and minimize it. It can be found in my [public github](https://github.com/FranciscoP/minimize/blob/master/minimize.php). For using it, just do:

```
if (file_exists('minimize.php')) =
  {
  include 'minimize.php';
  $Minimize = new Minimize();
  $Minimize->folder('/path/to/the/folder/','.css','/path/to/the/resulting/file/style.css');
  }
else
  echo "The minimizer file was not found, please make sure it's in this folder";
```